# mongo is it good idea to have two id's?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm filling-up my database with regions and districts. I'm taking data from csv which looks like this:

```
//regions (id,name)
1,First
2,Second

//districts (id,name,id of region)
1,some,2
2,test,1
3,something,1
```

Should I have in my mongodb those id's? Or should I rather replace those id's with mongo's default _id?

1.option

```
regions -> _id, name
districts -> _id, name, region_id
```

2.option

```
regions -> _id, region_id, name
districts -> _id, district_id, name, region_id
```

Or any other alternative? Thanks.

Comment: Question to option 2: Is your _id for districts the same as district_id? The same question goes for regions, is your _id for regions the same as region_id?

Comment: _id is generated automatically by mongo so there are some values like ObjectId("55fae4c7cb18045a7c0843e3")

Comment: Correct, but do you need a region_id for a field that already is unique?

Comment: I actually don't need it. If I use second option it's easier to import data but there's 1 field which is not necessary there with some updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first aren't really "_ids". They're an auto-incrementing field. This can be described in the [mongo docs here](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/). A [Mongo Object ID](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) is quite a bit more complex than just an incrementing field.

If you choose to overwrite mongo's _id, be sure to index it to be unique.

```
Meteor._ensureIndex({ index: id }, { unique: 1 });
```

Alternatively, if you don't actually need the autoincrementing field, you could just use mongo's ids.

Comment: I never came across _ensureIndex. Good one!